# How to copy data from USB to RAM

Tags: usb, memory, data-transfer

I am trying to quickly download images from a USB digital camera to a hard drive disk attached by USB to my raspberry pi. I want to minimize the time the camera needs to be connected to the pi during the download.

At the moment it seems to copy over to the hard drive at a rate of about 3-5MB/s depending on image size (I use gphoto2 for grabbing the images off the camera), which is OK but a little slow. I wanted to check what the speed was to copy just to the Pi's RAM, at which point I can disconnect the camera and later on move the files from the RAM to the hard drive at leisure.

Could anyone advise how I might be able to copy to RAM? I couldn't find a clear explanation anywhere...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It might help if we knew what the goal of this was? Why is minimizing the time the camera is connected etc.

Comment: for a project taking a long stream of photos (more than I can fit on an SD card) in periodic bursts, where the time between bursts (when I can transfer the data) needs to be minimized.

Comment: Just note that the Pi has limited RAM. A few photos is okay, but you can't fit an entire SD card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to create a RAM disk.

I use one simply to save wear and tear on the SD card.

Create a mount point on the SD card, e.g. /ram

```
mkdir /ram
```

The following command allocates a 100 MB ram disk and mounts it at /ram

```
sudo mount -osize=100m tmpfs /ram -t tmpfs
```

You could add the command (without the sudo) to the root crontab.